# create and add "li" element after click

Tags: javascript, function, click, addition

In an exercise, I have created a new element `li` after each click of my button. 
It doesn't work. In the console it reports "li is not defined".
What did I do wrong?

My code:

```
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
let number = 1;
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const fcn = function() {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = number;

}

if (number % 3 == 0) {
  li.classList.add('big');
}


ul.appendChild(li);
number += 2;

btn.addEventListener("click", fcn);
```

Comment: `const` has blocked scope, so you're not going to be able to access `li` outside the function block (`{}`). Also, you're calling `fcn` at some point in the future (when you click your button), whereas `li.classList.add('big');` will run when your JS script first runs, so even if you could access `li` outside your function, `li` wouldn't be defined yet since `fcn` wouldn't have initialized it yet. I'm guessing you intended your `if` and `ul.appendChild` etc... to be inside your function...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 const btn = document.querySelector("button");
 let number = 1;
 const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
 const fcn = function () {
 const li = document.createElement('li');
 li.textContent = number;



if (number % 3 == 0) {
li.classList.add('big');
}


ul.appendChild(li);
number += 2;

}
btn.addEventListener("click", fcn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to closures in javascript. li is not accessible outside function `fcn`.

`following code should solve your problem.`

```
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
let number = 0;
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const fcn = function () {
   number += 1;
   const li = document.createElement('li');
   li.textContent = number;
   ul.appendChild(li);

   if (number % 3 == 0) {
      li.classList.add('big');
   }

}
btn.addEventListener("click", fcn);
```

Answer (score 0):

`li` is defined within anonymous function.

When you define a variable/constant within function it's local to that function and can't be accessed outside it. It has function level scope.

To fix your code either define `li`  outside of function at global scope or move the piece of code that use it within function itself as follows :

```
  const btn = 
  document.querySelector("button");

  let number = 1;
  const ul = 
  document.querySelector("ul");

  const fcn = function () {
  const li = 
  document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = number;

  if(number % 3 == 0){
     li.classList.add('big');
  }

  ul.appendChild(li);
  number += 2;
}
  btn.addEventListener("click", fcn);
```